# Actualizar información de un campo de una tabla con el valor de un select

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un problema con una consulta.
Estoy tratando de completar una tabla donde pueda gestionar el permiso de ingreso a un usuario en específico pero no he logrado hacer que el valor de select sea el que reemplace el del campo que necesito.

Este el código de la tabla:

```
<table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>NOMBRE DEL USUARIO</th>
                            <th>CORREO</th>
                            <th>USUARIO</th>
                            <th>PERMISO DE INGRESO</th>
                            <th>MODIFICAR PERMISO</th>
                        </thead>

                        <?php include "php/config.php" ?>
                        <?php

                        mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
                        $peticion = "SELECT nombre, correo, usuario, permiso.descripcion FROM perfiles LEFT JOIN permiso ON perfiles.id_permiso = permiso.id";
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);
                        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

                            $html='<tr>
                            <td>'.$fila['nombre'].'</td> 
                            <td>'.$fila['correo'].'</td> 
                            <td>'.$fila['usuario'].'</td>
                            <td id="tabla_mod">'.$fila['descripcion'].'</td>
                            <td><select class="permiso">
                            <option disabled selected>Elegir</option>
                            <option value="1">Permitido</option>
                            <option value="2">Denegado</option>
                            </select></td>
                            </tr>';
                            echo $html;
                        }
                        ?>   
                    </table>
```

Intento hacer el envío de información por el siguiente script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
        $(".permiso").change(function(){
            $(".permiso option:selected").each(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.post("php/cambio_permisos.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("#tabla_mod").html(data);
            });
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

Y trato de usar esta consulta (que está en el php del $.post) aunque sé que está incorrecta e incompleta, pero la verdad es que no tengo la más minima idea de como formularla:

```
<?php          
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    $peticion = "UPDATE perfiles SET id_permiso = '".$POST['id']."' WHERE usuario = '".$fila['usuario']."' 
    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);
    mysqli_close($conexion);  
?>
```

Debo tener en cuenta que al usar el select sólo afecte al usuario que deseo y no toda la tabla como tal.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes modificar tu api para que reciba el id del usuario y el id del permiso, de esa manera haces un update haciendo un filtro por el usuario requerido.

```
<?php          
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    $permiso_id = $POST['pid'];
    $usuario_id = $POST['uid'];
    $peticion = "UPDATE perfiles SET id_permiso = '".$permiso_id ."' WHERE usuario = '".$usuario_id."' 
    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);
    mysqli_close($conexion);  
?>
```

De esta manera puedes asegurarte de modificar el usuario solicitado.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, es una muy buena idea aunque aún no lo resuelvo ya que no reconocería las variables de 'pid' y 'uid'

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice Eder, cualquier dato que vayas a necesitar en el servidor debes pasarlo desde el cliente en el segundo parámetro de `$.post()`. Actualmente sólo estás recogiendo y pasando el `id` de este modo: `{id:id}`

Aquí te muestro con un ejemplo cómo recoger y pasar el valor que haya en el `td` correspondiente a `$fila['usuario']` que creo que es el otro que necesitas. Para que el código se entienda mejor, he creado una variable `mData` con los dos valores y pasaremos esa variable en `$.post()`. **OJO al comentario en esa parte del código**.

Otra cosa es que esto sobra en tu código: `$(".permiso option:selected").each(function(){` lo he quitado y funciona perfectamente. Con esto `$(".permiso").change(function() {` el listener se aplica a cada elemento que tenga la clase `permiso`, por tanto no necesitas luego abrir un  `each` dentro.

Otra cosa es que en el código que crea los elementos de la tabla, estaría screando un HTML inválido, porque asignas el mismo `id` en esta celda: `<td id="tabla_mod">'.$fila['descripcion'].'</td>`, eso aunque no de error es incorrecto según el estandar HTML, según el cual dos elementos no pueden tener el mismo id. Y puede ocasionar fallos si intentas alcanzar modificar elementos por ese id.

Veamos el código:

## Cliente

```js
$(".permiso").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    /* Con td:eq(2) recuperamos el valor del td en la posición 2 de la fila */     
    var userID=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    /* Objeto que mandaremos al servidor */
    var mData={id:id, usuario:userID};
    console.log(mData); /*toDelete*/
    
    /* 
       *Comentamos este bloque para ver la prueba en el snippet
       *Habilítalo en tu contexto real
       *Nótese que ahora se envía mData en el 2º parámetro del post
    $.post("php/cambio_permisos.php", mData, function(data) {
      $("#tabla_mod").html(data);
    });
    */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>NOMBRE DEL USUARIO</th>
    <th>CORREO</th>
    <th>USUARIO</th>
    <th>PERMISO DE INGRESO</th>
    <th>MODIFICAR PERMISO</th>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td>Juan</td>
    <td>@</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>
      <select class="permiso">
        <option disabled selected>Elegir</option>
        <option value="1">Permitido</option>
        <option value="2">Denegado</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>María</td>
    <td>@</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>
      <select class="permiso">
        <option disabled selected>Elegir</option>
        <option value="1">Permitido</option>
        <option value="2">Denegado</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> He comentado la parte del `$.post` para que veas la prueba en el code
>   snippet. Por favor, descomentala en tu contexto real.

---

## Servidor

Si observas la salida del code snippet, verás que al servidor se está mandando este objeto:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "usuario": "77"
}
```

Entonces ya tendrás tus dos datos, que podrás recuperar en el `$_POST`.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Usamos ternarios para verificar si hay datos y recogerlos al mismo tiempo
$id=!empty($_POST["id"]) ? $_POST["id"] : NULL;
$usuario=!empty($_POST["usuario"]) ? $_POST["usuario"] : NULL;

if ($id && $usuario) {
    #Aquí usaremos las variables creadas en los ternarios. Esto aporta claridad
    $sql = "UPDATE perfiles SET id_permiso = '$id' WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    //ejecutar $sql, etc... 
}else{
    echo "Faltan datos";
}
```

### Recomendación sobre PHP

- Para estos casos te recomiendo encarecidamente a que uses consultas preparadas. Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.
- Si en la tabla la columna `id_permiso` es de tipo numérico, es mejor escribir la consulta así: `$sql = "UPDATE perfiles SET id_permiso = $id WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";`, o sea, no hay que rodear el valor de comillas simples en las columnas numéricas.